# Ajax Post to Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have a node app built using express and I've been trying for ages to send an ajax post request to the node server. However despite reading many answers to similar problems here I struggled to come to grips with even what files I should be editing. For a long time i was trying to use http.createServer in one of the routes.js files. This of course meant I could not run the server on the same port as the app as there was already a server instantiated in the bin -> www file. So this morning I edited the bin www file so that it would log a message when data was sent to it. However despite this function having worked when I tested it on a second server, the response no longer fires when i added it so the same function to the server in the bin-> www file. In fact I don't even think my ajax request is reaching the server anymore. Just to be clear the ajax request is written in script.js which is a client file in the public folder and is being sent to the node server which is instantiated in the bin -> www file. Here's my code:

```
***bin -> www file***


    var http = require('http');
    var util = require('util')
    var server = http.createServer(app,function (req, res) {
        console.log('Request received: ');
        util.log(util.inspect(req)) 
        util.log('Request recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url) 
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('GOT DATA!');
        got = chunk.toString(data);
        console.log(got)
        });
        res.end();

   }).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on port 3000')




***Script.js -> Client File***

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        data: '{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": ""}',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(ret)
            console.log('Success: ')
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + status);
        },
    });
```

Please Help! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Where are the route?

Comment: Never mind i got it. you're right the callback must be in the routes. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Do you managed to do?

Comment: @Lucas Costa yeah i threw my code down below there. If you are curious as why I'm making server requests like this: http://zaos.tk . that's the project I've been working on for a while. don't be too critical- I'm still in high school! :P

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it. instead of using ajax i just used a simple post request. mar shampla:

script.js (client)

```
$.post('/',
        {
            customData: favourites
        },
        function(data){
            console.log("message sent");
        });
```

and the server callback(in the route)

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

 var param = req.param('customData');
 console.log(param+" = new received post");
 console.log("old stormpath = "+req.user.customData.favLoi8ist);
 req.user.customData.favList = param;
 req.user.customData.save();

 newD = param;

 res.send(200, param);
});
```